# xml parsing and reading the values in python

Tags: python, xml

I want to know how to read and store the xml data in an array.I m not sure which method to use or class

Can anyone tell which xml lib to use for reading the xml

Comment: Wow, nice attitude. You might want to consider putting a bit more care into your questions if you are interested in good answers. Garbage in, garbage out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [#python](http://pound-python.org/) channel on FreeNode:

> When parsing XML or HTML, use the [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml) library

Answer (score 0):

That's quite a wide topic, and the best library depends on quite a few things, so it's not easy to answer this very meaningfully with so little details.

I'd suggest you look into [xml.dom.minidom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) and see if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup) or [xml](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python 2.5+, [xml.etree.ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is probably the easiest API to use in the stdlib.